# OnchangeListner in android for material spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi in the below code I was implemented a material spinner.For the spinner contains a list of items a,b,c,d,e,f .Now I am trying to implement the feature called edit.When click on edit option I am what are details available to spinner is b want to set to the existing spinner.

But it is not working with the below code.

```
String task_types = getArguments().getString("task_types");//output b
```

What I was tried i was added my string to my list but is giving me a duplicate values means b is displaying twice.

Below content is coming from the Api:

Now in the code already b already exist in the list.Now want to compare task_types with new value if already exist want to set the adapter to list.

```java
    for (PickListValues pickListValues1 : pickListValues) {

        value = pickListValues1.getValue();
        label=pickListValues1.getLabel();

        PickListValues pickListValues2=new PickListValues(value,label);
        pickListTask.add(pickListValues2);
        taskTypes.add(value);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getContext(),R.layout.spinner_item,taskTypes){// dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.borderdashboard.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            //spinnerlocation.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position){
                if(position == 0)
                {
                   return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;

                if(position+1 == 0){
                    // Set the hint text color gray

                    tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
                else {
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return view;
            }
        };
       // ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.borderdashboard.simple_spinner_item, taskTypes);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnertaskType.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        spinnertaskType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //                                                        String selectedItemText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if(position+1 > 0){

                    PickListValues pickListValues = pickListTask.get(position);
                    task_type_value = pickListValues.getValue();

                    Toast.makeText
                            (getContext(), "Selected : " + task_type_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    Log.e("ids", task_type_value);

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add a new item to the spinner view?

Comment: @No already existing element want to set to spinner.suppose b is output want to set b to spinner with creating new item (because b already exist in the list)

Comment: I still don't understand. Are you using google translate or something?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun when click on edit button task_types value is b.This b value want to set the spinner .

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun already existing item want to set to the spinner